# How to access a tag called "name" in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I want to access a tag called as `"name"` such as:

```
<contact><name>Yesügey</name><lastName>Yeşil</lastName><phone>+90 333 9695395</phone></contact>
```

Since `"name"` is a property of a BeautifulSoup tag object, I cannot access the child tag `name`:

```
>>> c1
<contact><name>Yesügey</name><lastname>Yeşil</lastname><phone>+90 333 9695395</p
hone></contact>
>>> c1.name
'contact'
>>> c1.lastname
<lastname>Yeşil</lastname>
```

Comment: Why don't you want a decent parser for XML like lxml or etree ?

Comment: I had the same question because kml uses <name> tags

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(content).findAll('name')
>>> for field in soup:
...     print field
... 
<name>Yesügey</name>
```

Or

```
print soup.find('name').string
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I got:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
soup = '<contact><name>Yesügey</name><lastName>Yeşil</lastName><phone>+90 333 9695395</phone></contact>'
soup = BS(soup)
print soup.find('name').string
# Prints YesĂźgey
```

So instead of calling the name tag, I simply find it and get what's inside it :).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.find()` method:

Examples:

`c2.find('name')`

> <name>Yesügey</name>

`c2.find('name').contents`

> Yesügey

Answer (score 0):

Described is two different stratgies of accessing xml element name

```
>>> xmlstring = '<contact><name>Yesügey</name><lastName>Yeşil</lastName><phone>+90 333    9695395</phone></contact>'
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as Soup
>>> f = Soup(xmlstring)
>>> f.find('name')
<name>YesĂźgey</name>
>>> f.contact.name
u'contact'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I had the same issue when trying to find a `<textarea name=COMMENTS>`

My solution:

`node = soup.find("textarea", attrs={"name": "COMMENTS"}`